# NUC6i3SYH wpa_supplicant not working with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, network-manager

I downloaded and installed ubuntu 16.04.1 on a fresh NUC6i3SYH but am having trouble with the wireless connection.  After debugging, it appears the problem is somewhere between wpa_supplicant and the driver.  On a fresh boot in /var/log/syslog, I see:

```
Aug 27 12:45:31 ada-desktop NetworkManager[2675]: <info>  [1472316331.3051] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Aug 27 12:45:31 ada-desktop NetworkManager[2675]: <info> [1472316331.3051] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Aug 27 12:45:31 ada-desktop wpa_supplicant[2958]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Aug 27 12:45:31 ada-desktop wpa_supplicant[2958]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Aug 27 12:45:31 ada-desktop wpa_supplicant[2958]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp1s0 flags: No such device
Aug 27 12:45:31 ada-desktop NetworkManager[2675]: <info>  [1472316331.3544] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Aug 27 12:45:31 ada-desktop NetworkManager[2675]: <info>  [1472316331.3545] device (wlp1s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Aug 27 12:45:31 ada-desktop kernel: [    6.009626] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
```

Any ideas?

Other symptoms/details:

When I click on the network icon, it shows a number of local wireless networks.  However, when I enter the password for my home wireless network it does nothing.  When I look in /var/log/syslog I see periodic messages saying:

```
... wpa_supplicant[...]: wlp1s0: Failed to initiate sched scan
```

when I run lspci -nnk I see:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
      Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:9010]
      Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
      Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

when I look in /var/log/kern.log I see messages consistent with a happy driver.

I've never run into a situation where you can scan the network then the system does not work.

A few more details:
(1) Via wired network, I did a sudo apt-get upgrade.  Doesn't help.
(2) I also update the bios firmware.  Doesn't help.

When I tail /var/log/syslog, I see:

```
Aug 25 20:10:09 ada-desktop NetworkManager[2747]: <warn>  [1472170209.1025] device (wlp1s0): No agents were available for this request.
Aug 25 20:10:09 ada-desktop NetworkManager[2747]: <info>  [1472170209.1026] device (wlp1s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
Aug 25 20:10:09 ada-desktop NetworkManager[2747]: <info>  [1472170209.1034] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug 25 20:10:09 ada-desktop NetworkManager[2747]: <warn>  [1472170209.1046] device (wlp1s0): Activation: failed for connection '2CNC9'
Aug 25 20:10:09 ada-desktop NetworkManager[2747]: <info>  [1472170209.1068] device (wlp1s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Aug 25 20:10:09 ada-desktop kernel: [  235.762708] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
Aug 25 20:10:10 ada-desktop wpa_supplicant[2926]: wlp1s0: Failed to initiate sched scan
```

With Network-Manager turned off, I tried to configure things manually and got stuck.  These succeed:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp1s0 up
sudo ifconfig wlp1s0 192.168.1.223succeeds.
sudo ifconfig wlp1s0 netmask 255.255.255.255
sudo iwconfig wlp1s0 essid 2CNC9
```

But this fails:

```
sudo iwconfig wlp1s0 key s:longpassphrase
```

with error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    SET failed on device wlp1s0 ; Invalid argument.
```

Apparently this is because I need to worry about wpa_supplicant.